# QPushButton text offset

Tags: c++, qt, offset, caption, qpushbutton

I'd like to have a Qt widget (`QPushButton`), in which caption starts(!) from the center. How can I achieve it? I use Qt 5.12.x, C++, Windows. Is rewriting `paintEvent` the only way? I'd like to study "math" sample for it.

Comment: Have you looked into Qt style sheets? If not, do that first. Another method might be to paint your text on image, and show that instead of text in the button.

Comment: I am aware about stylesheets, but `text-align` does not fit my needs.

Comment: What about QLabel? How can I add it over dummy `QWidget` instance starting from center?

Comment: You can probably achive this with a spacer item and QHBoxLayout, if you configure them properly (size policies and weights). But if you are having your own QWidget subclass *anyway*, and it has this simple contents, you can just override resize event, and in there set the geometory of QLabel according to the new size (this is sometimes called "manual layout").